# Angular JS and Unobtrusive JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just getting into learning MVC and Angular and I'm curious about code such as the following (taken from angularjs.org)

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Todo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Todo</h2>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining</span> [ <a href="" ng-click="archive()">
            archive</a> ]
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span> </li>
        </ul>
        <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" size="30" placeholder="">
        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Todo.js

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [
    { text: 'learn angular', done: true },
    { text: 'build an angular app', done: false}];

    $scope.addTodo = function () {
        $scope.todos.push({ text: $scope.todoText, done: false });
        $scope.todoText = '';
    };

    $scope.remaining = function () {
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.todos, function (todo) {
            count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
        });
        return count;
    };

    $scope.archive = function () {
        var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
        $scope.todos = [];
        angular.forEach(oldTodos, function (todo) {
            if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
        });
    };
}
```

If the tenets of unobtrusive javascript say that we need to separate behavior from presentation, why is it OK and best practice for angular to have code like `ng-click=archive()`?

Comment: AngularJS is not unobtrusive.

Comment: You could always try this: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-with-no-custom-markup Though... It'd be a pain...

Comment: @SLaks Yeah, I could gather that much.  I'm just curious what makes this 'OK'.  Is it because obtrusiveness is essential for MV* to work, or this is the best that exists at the moment?

Comment: Angular goes for a declarative approach.

Comment: And that archive() run twice on every changes as far as I noticed :P

Comment: @elclanrs I'm just trying to wrap my head around why it can be more useful to NOT have your presentation and behavior separated.  I suppose if you use a SPA framework then it doesn't really make sense to tease them apart because angular is `HTML for web apps and not web pages`?? Would that seem a fair assessment?

Comment: Well, one still can migrate from `jquery_ujs` to this:
https://github.com/tomchentw/angular-ujs

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question. I disagree with the close.

Comment: I agree, great question. Please re-open.

Comment: To me that is more like an example on agularjs site, but there's nothing to suggest that's the best practice or even OK.  Great question, but to avoid doing so, you can write a directive.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie I think the answer lies somewhere in the way that just like angular requires its own way of thinking (usually referred to as the angular way) so does unobtrusive javascript. Not everything makes perfect sense for all use cases. It's the roi you (and your users and fellow developers) receive in return for following a particular thinking paradigm which is most important. More so than just following some tenets just because popular opinion currently says it is so. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 8):

Unobtrusive javascript is an older concept that doesn't carry the same importance as it once did. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript),

> Adherents to "Unobtrusive JavaScript" argue that the purpose of markup
>   is to describe a document's structure, not its programmatic behavior
>   and that combining the two negatively impacts a site's
>   maintainability.

**Usability** is not relevant because no one looks at your DOM code except your development team.  Inline event handlers are easier to maintain once you embrace the Angular philosophy.  Though, you could always use [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) to keep your HTML cleaner.

As the Angular website best puts it,

> AngularJS lets you extend HTML vocabulary for your application. The
>   resulting environment is extraordinarily expressive, readable, and
>   quick to develop.

Search engines may have a slightly harder time indexing your site but we have RSS, Sitemaps and [AJAX Crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) to get around that.

**Graceful Degradation** is no longer relevant, unless your building apps for a non-smart phone market.  Almost all users are on a browser that supports modern javascript (with shims).

**Accessibility** and Angular don't conflict.  Just make sure to use ARIA tags and proper markup.  Angular makes it easier to write testable code and has built in [exception handling](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler).

**Separation of Concerns** is an issue if you are polluting the global scope with functions.   Angular makes it easier to maintain javascript code separately without impacting other files or code.

Comment: Suggestions for improvement: 1) citation for "doesn't carry the same importance as it once did." 2) citation for "Graceful degredation is no longer relevent..."  Without citations for these statements, they seem like dangerously misguided opinions.

Answer (score 2):

I came to the same conclusion as I learn angular. I don't mind html attributes for data, but we have been trying not to do onclick or any other events on html tags for a long time. Evaluated expressions make me even more squeamish. like ng-model-setter="set($value)" . This feels like it belongs in javascript, not out in the markup.

Comment: At the end of the day, does it really matter?

Comment: I think thinking about the matter does

Comment: Depends on how maintainable you want your code to be. 
If you try and put all logic in the javascript-file ( app file) and only do the databinding, then you know where you may look for errors in the code. 
If you are mixing setters in the markup and in the javascript, the code _may_ be harder to maintain. 
One great source on how to make webapplications with angular could be this one: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide